# Irregular Background Movement Speed

Tags: java

I am currently making a side scroller, and I've been working on the moving background. Here is the class that I use to manage it's movement:

```
package game;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import framework.GClock;

public class BackgroundManager {
public BufferedImage background;
public BufferedImage[] movingImages;
private final int y=4,x=2;
public final int scale = 3;
private float[] speed;
private Rectangle[][] rects;
private float speedScale =150f;

public BackgroundManager() {
    try {
        URL bg = BackgroundManager.class
                .getResource("/resources/background.png");
        background = ImageIO.read(bg);
        URL[] urls = new URL[4];
        urls[0] = BackgroundManager.class
                .getResource("/resources/mountainBackground.png");
        urls[1] = BackgroundManager.class
                .getResource("/resources/mountainForeground.png");
        urls[2] = BackgroundManager.class
                .getResource("/resources/treesBackground.png");
        urls[3] = BackgroundManager.class
                .getResource("/resources/treesForeground.png");

        movingImages = new BufferedImage[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
            movingImages[i] = ImageIO.read(urls[i]);

        }

        int bgw = background.getWidth()*scale;

        speed = new float[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
            speed[i] = speedScale * (movingImages[i].getWidth()*scale
                    / bgw-1);
            System.out.println(speed[i]);
            // maybe use
            // Image.getScaledInstance(scaledWidth,scaledHeight,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
        }
        rects = new Rectangle[x][y];
        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
            rects[0][i] = new Rectangle(0, 0,
                    movingImages[i].getWidth()*scale,
                    movingImages[i].getHeight()*scale);
            rects[1][i] = new Rectangle(rects[0][i].width,
                    0, movingImages[i].getWidth()*scale,
                    movingImages[i].getHeight()*scale);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void update(GClock clock) {
    float dt = clock.getElapsedTime();

    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        if (rects[0][i].x + rects[0][i].width < -10)
            rects[0][i].x = rects[1][i].x + rects[1][i].width;
        if (rects[1][i].x + rects[1][i].width < -10)
            rects[1][i].x = rects[0][i].x + rects[0][i].width;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        rects[0][i].x -= speed[i] * dt;
        rects[1][i].x -= speed[i] * dt;
    }
}

public void drawBackground(Graphics2D g) {
    //static background
    g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, background.getWidth() * scale,
            background.getHeight() * scale, null);
    //other layers
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        g.drawImage(movingImages[i], rects[0][i].x, 0,
                rects[0][i].width,
                rects[0][i].height, null);
        g.drawImage(movingImages[i], rects[1][i].x, 0,
                rects[1][i].width,
                rects[1][i].height, null);

    }
/*
    // background
    g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, background.getWidth() * scale,
            background.getHeight() * scale, null);
    // mountainBackground
    g.drawImage(mountainBackground, (int) (-speed[0] * dt), 0,
            mountainBackground.getWidth() * scale,
            mountainBackground.getHeight() * scale, null);
    // mountainForeground
    g.drawImage(mountainForeground, (int) (-speed[1] * dt), 0,
            mountainForeground.getWidth() * scale,
            mountainForeground.getHeight() * scale, null);
    // treesBackground
    g.drawImage(treesBackground, (int) (-speed[2] * dt), 0,
            treesBackground.getWidth() * scale, treesBackground.getHeight()
                    * scale, null);
    // treesForeground
    g.drawImage(treesForeground, (int) (-speed[3] * dt), 0,
            treesForeground.getWidth() * scale, treesForeground.getHeight()
                    * scale, null);
*/
    }
}
```

`GClock` is a class I made to manage time, and `clock.getElapsedTime()` is the amount of time the last update->draw->repaint->sleep cycle took.

For some reason, instead of moving the first image to the right side of the next image to simulate a continuous background, it does [this](https://gyazo.com/775762147d83a1436dc4052181f9e2a0). In the clip, the next layer speeds up until it reaches the left side of the screen, and then matches the speed of the last layer. I've tried removing the block of code that switches the position of the bounding rectangles, and I've spent about an hour on top of that trying to figure this out, but no luck. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Here are the relevant fields for GClock:

```
private long startTime;
private long dt;
private long lastTime;
private float targetTime;
private boolean isFpsCapped;

public GClock(){
    startTime=lastTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    targetTime=1f/60f;
    isFpsCapped=true;


}   
protected void update(){
    this.dt=System.currentTimeMillis()-lastTime;    
    this.lastTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
}
public float getElapsedTime(){
    return (float)dt/1000f;

}
```

Here's the gameloop:

```
while(isRunning){
        clock.update();//calculates the amount of time that the last game loop took and prepares for the next clock.update() call.
        if(!isPaused){
        this.update(clock);//update is an abstract method that is implemented into child classes. For this instance, it only contains BackgroundManager.update(clock);

        this.render(clock);//render is a method that manages the game's Graphics2D object, and calls this.draw(), which, like update(), is an abstract method called only by implementations of this class.
        this.paintScreen();//repains the screen
        }

        if(clock.isFpsCapped()){
            //thread.sleep(millis);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(clock.calculateSleepTime());//makes the thread sleep for a certain amount of time, so that the amount of time the gameloop took + calculateSleepTime() = some target time (in this case, it tries to keep the game at about 60 fps.)
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }//end of if statement
    }
```

Comment: Your update method looks reasonably sound, as you're taking the delta time into account. Perhaps it would be worthwhile for you to include the code from the getElapsedTime() method? And, as a side note, there's some duplication there regarding your arrays rects[0] and rects[1]. You could loop through them with an inner loop from 0 to 1.

Comment: @ManoDestra I added the relevant GClock fields. Also, I know I could iterate through rects[0] and rects[1] with a for loop, but there's only two of them, so I didn't.

Comment: it doesnt make sense to me - what you are trying to do - you have two images and you are mixing scale factors etc. - maybe someone can figure it out

Comment: What kind of timer code are you using to run the game loop and hence call update() on both your GClock and BackgroundManager? Seems a little unusual to me that GClock has an update() method. I would have thought that your game loop would simply create a GClock bean based on its timing and then pass it to components for their update() methods. No matter. What code runs the game loop? I'm trying to replicate your issue at the moment in order to assist P.S. Love the style of your game so far! Nice parallax :)

Comment: @ManoDestra edited. Also, thanks for the kind words :)